# SQL Join Issues

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I am trying to join a few tables together, one of which is the same join on the same table, with different conditions. I am getting outputs on my query, but not on one unified line. Example:

```
    select distinct  rfp.id, title, bidtype, rfp.createdon as '#1', s.finishedDt as '#2', c.id as 'Contract #', supp.rfp_contr_supplier_name, es.suppdate as '#3', es2.suppdate as '#4'
  from TBL_RFP_Ideas_NEW rfp
left join tbl_rfp_senior s on rfp.id = s.ideaid
left join rfp_contract c on rfp.id = c.ideaid
inner join supplier_view supp on contractnbr = c.id
left join TBL_EmpMaster_Full emp on rfp.sponsor_empid = emp.empid
left join rfp_events e on rfp.id = e.ideaid
left join rfp_events_suppliers es on e.id = es.event_id and e.heading = '4' and e.description = 'Master Agreement effective date'
left join rfp_events_suppliers es2 on e.id = es2.event_id and e.heading = '5' and e.description = 'Master Agreement Rollout date'
where rfp.id = '683311'
group by rfp.id, title, bidtype, rfp.createdon, s.finishedDt, c.id, supp.rfp_contr_supplier_name, es.suppdate, es2.suppdate, e.description
```

[image: This gets output with the following Query]

I can elaborate some on the table architecture if need be, but the joins pretty much explain how its built. Im hoping im missing something insanely small. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Are you aware that `distinct` operates on the entire row and not just on `rfp.id`?

Comment: Mention your a  raw data and how your result looks like?

Comment: If you are going to use "group by" then you should also be using some aggregate function (such as Min or Max) in your select statement.  Then remove fields used in the aggregate function from the "group by".  Then remove "DISTINCT" since your "group by" is removing duplicates and the "distinct" is redundant.

Comment: Why GROUP BY when no aggregate functions are used?

Comment: I am aware that distinct operates on the entire row, yes. I was trying to use distinct originally to get rid of the nulls im returning. The issue is that the dates for #3 and 4 are there, but wont output as one row, but instead as multiple rows with seemingly no differences. Is this because of the group by?

Answer (score 2):

The multiple rows are occurring because there are 3 records in `tbl_rfp_senior` that match that id and probably 3 records in `rfp_events` as well (hard to tell without the data. You either need to add additional criteria to your joins to eliminate the extra rows (e.g. deactivation_date is not null? or active = 1 are some thoughts) or use min and max or some other aggregate like sum to get the single results of interest and remove those fields from the grouping. I would also suggest that where distinct and group by are both present there is code smell :-)

To help debug this issue I would start by selecting * and getting rid of the group by and identifying where the multiple rows are coming from and where you need to do aggregates.

Comment: This is a great idea. I'm going to try this out. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

```
select distinct  
        rfp.id, title, bidtype, rfp.createdon as '#1', s.finishedDt as '#2', c.id as 'Contract #', supp.rfp_contr_supplier_name, es.suppdate as '#3', es2.suppdate as '#4'
from 
        TBL_RFP_Ideas_NEW rfp
        left join 
        (
            Select  distinct    ideaid,finishedDt
            From    tbl_rfp_senior
        )s 
        on rfp.id = s.ideaid
        left join 
        rfp_contract c 
        on rfp.id = c.ideaid
        inner join 
        supplier_view supp 
        on contractnbr = c.id
        left join 
        TBL_EmpMaster_Full emp 
        on rfp.sponsor_empid = emp.empid
        left join 
        rfp_events e 
        on rfp.id = e.ideaid
        left join 
        rfp_events_suppliers es 
        on e.id = es.event_id and e.heading = '4' and e.description = 'Master Agreement effective date'
        left join
        rfp_events_suppliers es2 
        on e.id = es2.event_id and e.heading = '5' and e.description = 'Master Agreement Rollout date'
where rfp.id = '683311'
group by rfp.id, title, bidtype, rfp.createdon, s.finishedDt, c.id, supp.rfp_contr_supplier_name, es.suppdate, es2.suppdate, e.description
```